# Receive Jquery/Ajax Post Request in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have Jquery/Ajax Code which sends Text Fields Data to PHP Script. But i don't know how i can receive that data and process for Validation.
Here is the Ajax Code:

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
var dataa = $("#survay").serialize();

var data = $("#yourName ,#emailAdress , #phoneNumber , #zipCode").serialize();


 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'processRequest.php',
  data: dataa,
 beforeSend : function(){
  $('.eDis').empty().append('<div class="loader"><img src="images/32.gif" /> Loading...</div>').show();
 },
  success: function (html) {
  if(html !='1') {
  $('.eDis').empty().append(html).addClass("actEr");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.eDis').removeClass("actEr")}, 5000);

  }

  if(html == '1') {

   $('.eDis').empty().append('<div class="success">Your Message has been sent</div>').addClass("actEr");
   window.location ='../thank-you.html';

  }
  if(html =='0') {    $('.eDis').empty().append('Error..').addClass("actEr");   setTimeout(function(){
    $('.eDis').removeClass("actEr")}, 3000);

  }} 
});
});
```

processRequest.php should be PHP script which will handle all the texts fields data.
If above Text fields data is valid then i want it to Proceed further and redirect the page to thank-you.html

.eDis is CSS class, which i want to use to display valid,Invalid fields information.
It is in HTML.

Comment: Do you mean that you want someone to write the PHP script for you?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your information, I can't give you exact code, but, this is what you can do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['itemName']) && isset($_POST['anotherItemName']) /* ...and so on */){
    if($_POST['itemName'] == $validSomething)
        echo 'WOW!';
}
else
    echo 'error';
?>
```

What you are "echoing" is what you get in "success" data in your javascript.